# What is the difference between 'as if it were nothing' or 'as if it was nothing'

Tags: tenses

I have two sentences. In the first I used *were*. A friend of mine said that you can also use *was*, as there is no difference. In my opinion the first sentence sounds more correct but I am not sure why.

> The dog jumped over the couch **as if it were nothing**.
>
> The dog jumped over the couch **as if it was nothing**.

Do you know what the different meaning is between these two sentences?

Comment: Are you using "it" to refer to the couch, or to the jump?

Comment: @Davo In this case I am referring to the couch.

Answer (score 1):

This is an area where English has been changing over the last fifty or a hundred years; and it is also a matter of the level of formality.

The sort of people who believe that there is only one "correct" English, and everything else is "incorrect", will tell you that it has to be "were" here, for a counter-factual conditional. Those people will look down on anybody who uses "was".

Many people always use "were" here; some use "were" in writing, but are as likely to use "was" in speech; some people always use "was".

If you don't want to be judged as "incorrect", use "were". If you are happy to speak English the way many (but certainly not all) use it, you can use "was".